# multiple smoke simulations - independent of each other

Tags: smoke-simulation

it's more like a general question:

I made a smoke simulation, one domain + one emitter -> baked that, worked fine.

Then i added another domain + emitter, where the domain is that big, that the emitter of the already baked domain is in it.

I hoped, that the baked smoke + emitter wouldn't influence the new domain, but it did.

Question: how do i prevent that from happening? or how can i have overlapping domains which are "just" reacting to "special" emitters? Is there a trick i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which emitters and effectors are used in each domain by placing each domains grouping of those objects into different collections and then specifying to only use that collection in the domain's Field Weights *Effector Collection* field:

[image]

For fun I offer a free sample that I call "dual smoking skulls", a nice Halloween treat! [image]

[image]